# How do Python nonlocal and global work together?

Tags: python, closures

This is my example

```
x=0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def i1():
        nonlocal x
        x = 2
        print("inner1:", x)

    i1()
    print("outer:", x)

    def i2():
        nonlocal x
        x = 3
        print("inner2:", x)

    i2()
    print("outer:", x)

    def i3():
        global x
        print("inner3:", x)

    i3()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)
```

Output in my Jupyter

```
inner1: 2
outer: 2
inner2: 3
outer: 3
inner3: 0
outer: 3
global: 0
```

Why does outer have value 0?

Comment: *"Why does outer have value 0?"* According to your output, it has a value of 3.

Comment: If you're asking about the *global* `x`, well, that's because you never assign a value other than 0 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test case has a bug.  If I change `i3` to:

```
    def i3():
        global x
        x = "i3"
        print("inner3:", x)
```

then I get

```
global: i3
```

at the end, as I would expect.

Comment: You are assigning string to x

Comment: Yes, so that it's clear that the assignment is coming from `i3`. The number 3 is already used elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

In `i3()`, when you declare `global x`, it indeed uses the outermost `x`, but you haven't changed its value.

In this part of the code:

```
i3()
print("outer:", x)
```

The `print` command is outside the `i3()` method, hence the global `x` is **NOT** being used. It is the local `x` which will be used. The `global` command in `i3()` means that only the `x` used within `i3()` will be global. Once outside `i3()`, the declared `global` scope for `x` will end.

Thus, `print("outer:", x)` prints 3, which is the `outer()` method's local variable's value. The outermost `x` remains 0 throughout.